# How can I install a smart thermostat with my HVAC system?

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I have a Ruud furnace / air handler with a non-programmable thermostat installed.  It looks to be a model RGPE-07EBRQR (Rheem?). I want to put in an Ecobee and am a bit confused about the wiring.

The wiring diagram for the furnace:

[image: Wiring diagram on furnace]
[image: Mfr sticker]

The existing wiring looks like:

[image: Wiring at furnace]

[image: Close up of thermostat wiring block]

The wiring at the t-stat is:

[image: Existing thermostat wiring]

Some more description about the pictures - the thermostat only has 5 wires available, so I think I need to run new cable to provide at least 1 more. At the furnace, there are 2 cables coming in - 1 from the t-stat and 1 out to the AC compressor (I assume). The wire from the t-stat into the furnace is spliced right before it goes into the furnace with an 8-conductor cable. That 8-conductor cable is visible in the overall picture of the furnace wiring on the top-left side (all but 5 of the wires are cut short). There is a wire under the C terminal at the furnace but that doesn't go up to the t-stat.

My thought is to run a new 7-conductor cable (I have some already) from the t-stat to the furnace, splicing in with the existing 8-conductor cable at the furnace. Then take one of the wires that is cut short in the existing 8-conductor cable and add it to the C terminal on the left side of the board (with the existing blue wire). Then connect the Ecobee using the 5 current wires in the same terminals plus the new wire routed to the C terminal.

Will that work or am I off base?

Comment: It's hard to trace the wires in the picture, but if the stat doesn't have a "c" then the wire on in the furnace must go to the "c" in AC unit. So why would you mess with that cable if it already has a "c" and all you need is an additional conductor between the furnace and the stat?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease i don't plan on messing with the cable to the ac. Just the one to the t-stat. I would leave the existing blue on the C terminal and add a second wire from the stat cable (can i have 2 wires under one terminal or do i need to pigtail?)

Comment: Sorry, thought the 8 wire was the wire to the AC. Is the cable from the AC long enough to reach the furnace control board? What you describe would work. I would prefer to eliminate unnecessary splices and run the new cable direct to the furnace circuit board, and just use the 8 conductor to stretch the AC control wires into the furnace.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have more wires hiding back there at the thermostat end you can splice onto, for that matter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yeah, i pulled the cable out of the wall more to confirm

Comment: Where is the existing splice between the 5-conductor and the 8-conductor cables made at?

Comment: Splice is right outside the furnace. Running the cable is not a problem, i just want to make sure i get the connections right

Comment: @mmathis -- I know this is way later, but can you get us a photo of that splice, or an answer as to how you solved this for that matter?